# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/@modules/vue.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, import, vee-validate

I have a problem using a form validation named Vee Validate in Vue.js. I'm a beginner and not fully understand the import syntax. I install the vee-validate using `npm i vee-validate --save` and it was placed in my node_modules. Now I import it in my main.js module and use the code given on the official page:

```
import { extend } from 'vee-validate';
import { required } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'; 

extend('required', {
  ...required,
  message: 'This field is required'
});
```

But when I open the index.html it gives an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/@modules/vue.js' does not provide an export named 'default'
```

Here is the link to vee-validate package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vee-validate?activeTab=readme

Thank you for helping me. Forgive me if my question is not clear.

Comment: Are you using vue 3?
I've had this error because somewhere in my (old vue 2) codebase there was something like this:
`import Vue from 'vue';`

Comment: @PhilippMildenberger yes I already figure it out. That's exactly my problem. Thank you very much, sir!

Comment: Care to share the solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem when I made the migration to vuejs 3.

This: `import Vue from 'vue';` has to be changed to:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'

const app = createApp({})
```

Take a look to the guide:
https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#a-new-global-api-createapp

Comment: I am not the TS, but thanks Nadia. I've been looking for this for 2 hours.